# Flash message if a user clicks a link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise, flash-message

I have a couple of links of my home page to different parts of my site that are restricted to those who are logged in.

If you are not logged in then you are redirected to the sign up form.

This isn't great however so i'd like to first of all redirect the user back to my home page. As well as display a flash message at the top of the screen informing them that they must be signed in first to proceed.

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#lib/custom_authentication_failure.rb
class CustomAuthenticationFailure < Devise::FailureApp 

  protected 

  def redirect_url 
    root_url
  end 
end

# /config/initializers/devise.rb
Devise.setup do |config|
...
  config.warden do |manager|
    manager.failure_app = CustomAuthenticationFailure
  end
end
```

If you’re getting an uninitialized constant CustomAuthenticationFailure error, and you’ve put the CustomAuthenticationFailure class under your /lib directory, make sure to autoload your lib files in your application.rb file:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

You have to be sure that the page where you redirect the user does not require authentication.

From http://adamtrepanier.net/post/7622315219/devise-authenticate-user-and-redirect and https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages

*edit:*
I assume that you are using `authenticate_user!`, to restrict access.

Comment: @Keva161, have you tried to restart the server? Also check out the class name that you declared, and which is added.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine `redirect_to` and a flash message in the single statement:

```
redirect_to root_url, alert: "You're guest. That page was for users only :-)"
```